# fMailbox to get most recent email in array

Tags: php, arrays, max

I'm using fMailbox class from flourish to get access to my emails.  My ultimate goal is to periodically find the most recent email and download the .txt file.  The array returned using fMailbox looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [received] => 06 Aug 2016 14:03:25 -0400
            [size] => 2836
            [date] => Sat, 06 Aug 2016 14:03:25 -0400
            [from] => "Mail Delivery System" 
            [subject] => Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
            [message_id] => 
            [to] => "NIL" 
        )`

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [received] => 06 Aug 2016 14:08:14 -0400
            [size] => 4733
            [date] => Sat, 6 Aug 2016 18:07:14 +0000
            [from] => "Jerry West" 
            [subject] => Test
            [message_id] => <2C49E7@KRABBY.owen.edu>
            [to] => "JWest@domain.com"
```

They are sorted in ascending order by date, and there are large gaps between array items, so the numbers may go [1] [2] [6] [30].  I would like to find the most recent message, or the highest number.  The max($array) function is returning [6] as the max entry rather than [30].  Why is this function not returning [30] for the array?

Answer (score 0):

`echo max(array_column($messages, 'uid'));`

Comment: It's better to include some explanation of the code with the answer (rather than just posting code).